# ACCESS-match two tables for requirements and available and update requirement until zero

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables to compare and match in MS-Access. 2 tables shown below and result I am trying to achieve is 3rd table.

Table1
Project Code    Prod. Order No.      Current AICD         Balance
TT/21-22/079    PROD/21-22/00064    RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR    1718
TT/21-22/079    PROD/23-24/04240    RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR    3550
TT/21-22/079    PROD/23-24/04241    RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR    2384

Table2
Project Code    Item No.               Entry No. Remaining Quantity
TT/21-22/079    RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR    2591897 180000
TT/21-22/079    RS27C150X75X6.5X10JR    2532802 102033

[requirements table with each project number and item number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXqWa.png)
[available quantity with project number and item number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0hPA.png) 
[desired results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsUd4.png)

I am trying to make the desired output table where the balance subtracts itself from the entry item remaining quantity until it requirement is complete.